# WebAPI don't deserialize JSON but same payload works in Swagger

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api, deserialization, .net-4.5

I have a WebAPI that has been in use for the last 7 years (.NET 4.7), it's been working without a hitch since the first release. Since March 10th, all of a sudden, it simply refuses to deserialize the JSON payload that gets posted to it.

The model looks like this:

```
[XmlType(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "http://dataprocessor.com/payload")]
    public class DataReq
    {
        [XmlElement(Form = XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(Form = XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
        public string B64Payload { get; set; }
    }
```

And the controller looks like this:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("api/processdata")]
public ResponseObj ProcessReport([FromBody]DataReq payLoad)
{
    using (DataProcessing dp = new DataProcessing())
    {
       ResponseObj response = dp.ProcessData(payLoad);
       return response;
    }
}
```

I've also set up a function in order to dump the incoming request body which I then write to a file:

```
private async Task<string> GetRawPostData()
{
    using (var contentStream = await Request.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
    {
        contentStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        using (var sr = new StreamReader(contentStream))
        {
            return sr.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
}
```

But if I post a payload I get something along the lines of this:

```
{
    "name": "Testpayload",
    "b64Payload": "SGVsbG8gd29ybGQ="
}
```

I get null from it when debugging it in VS, it simply can't deserialize it by the looks of it. It has, as I said, for the last 7 years, but not anymore.

HOWEVER, if I take the payload that I dumped in the `GetRawPostData()` and paste it into the Swagger page of the API, it goes through without any problems whatsoever.

I've been struggling with this all day but I simply cannot get my head around this, please help!

Comment: ` Since March 10th, all of a sudden, it simply refuses to deserialize the JSON payload that gets posted to it` that's not how software works. Something has changed somewhere, maybe a Windows update, and the only one who can figure out that change is you, not us.

Comment: Yeah, that much I know, it's basically just a question to see if anyone else has faced the same issue and have some hint on where to look, there's been no updates installed and the server hasn't been touched since then, which makes it that much harder to troubleshoot.

Answer (score 1):

Finally found an answer after even more bits and pieces.
[ASP.NET Web Api - the framework is not converting JSON to object when using Chunked Transfer Encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26111850/asp-net-web-api-the-framework-is-not-converting-json-to-object-when-using-chun)

Exactly why this just happened, no idea, but at least it's a fix.